# Como salvar os dados em um arquivo?

Tags: python

Estou consumindo uma API do Facebook business e preciso colocar os dados em um arquivo TXT ou CSV.

Quando imprimo o resultado com `print`, sai como esperado, mas não consigo colocar as linhas em um arquivo txt.

Saída com `print`:

```
[Anhanguera] - VALINHOS/SP - Saldo : R$ 5755
[Anhanguera] - PASSO FUNDO/RS - Saldo : R$ 58157
[Anhanguera] - CAXIAS DO SUL/RS - Saldo : R$ 108708
[Anhanguera] - JARAGUA DO SUL/SC - Saldo : R$ 117410
[Anhanguera] - RIO CLARO/SP - Saldo : R$ 36804
[Pitagoras] - JABOATAO DOS GUARARAPES/PE - Saldo : R$ 40744
[Pitagoras] - IRECE/BA - Saldo : R$ 59997
[Anhanguera] - SAO JOSE DO RIO PRETO/SP - Saldo : R$ 34776
[Pitagoras] - JUIZ DE FORA/MG - Saldo : R$ 45540
[Anhanguera] - MANAUS/AM - Saldo : R$ 118413
[Anhanguera] - ERECHIM/RS - Saldo : R$ 50044
[Anhanguera] - NOVA IGUACU/RJ - Saldo : R$ 103828
[Anhanguera] - FRANCA/SP - Saldo : R$ 18543
[Pitagoras] - ITABIRA/MG - Saldo : R$ 118318
[Anhanguera] - ASSIS/SP - Saldo : R$ 47249
```

Preciso por esses dados em um aquivo TXT bem como está apresentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema, você deve criar um arquivo, e escrever a saída do seu print no arquivo. Em meu exemplo `inputdata` seria o seu array de dados

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for linha in inputdata:
        f.write(linha)
```

Neste exemplo o parâmetro `w` quer dizer que estamos criando um arquivo e desejamos escrever dados.

Recomendo a documentação para entender como funciona o comando open, e verificar outras opções para escrever em arquivo.

[Documentação open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!